# $c_n= \prod^n_{m=0} \frac {a_m}{a_m-2(b_m-b_{m+1})}. \text{Find the smallest value of n} \in \mathbb{N}\, \text{for which}\, c_n < 0.01.$

Tags: summation, problem-solving, products

I've been stuck on this question for quite a while now.

$\forall m, n\in \mathbb{N}\, \text{we define}\, a_m = \sum^m_{k = 0} (\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+1})^{-1}\, , b_m =  \sum^m_{k = 0} (\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k+2})^{-1}\, and\, c_n= \prod^n_{m=0} \frac {a_m}{a_m-2(b_m-b_{m+1})}. \text{Find the smallest value of n} \in \mathbb{N}, \text{if any}, \text{for which}\, c_n < 0.01.$

I tried to rewrite $c_n$ algebraically but I was only able to come up with $$c_n= \prod^n_{m=0} \frac {a_m(\sqrt{m+1}+\sqrt{m+3})}{a_m(\sqrt{m+1}+\sqrt{m+3})-2}.$$
by simplifying $(b_m - b_{m+1})$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}+\sqrt{m+3}}$. I can't seem to do much with $a_m$ so I'm just not sure where to go from here or if I'm even in the right direction.

Forgive me if this is a bad post, I'm new to the website.

Comment: $n=139$ by trial and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_m=\sum _{k=0}^m \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}=\sum _{k=0}^m (\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})=\sqrt{m+1}$

$b_m=\sum _{k=0}^m \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+2}+\sqrt{k}}=\dfrac{1}{2}\,\sum _{k=0}^m (\sqrt{k+2}-\sqrt{k})=\dfrac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{m+1}+\sqrt{m+2}-1\right)$

$b_m-b_{m+1}=\dfrac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{m+1}-\sqrt{m+3}\right)$

$\dfrac {a_m}{a_m-2(b_m-b_{m+1})}=\dfrac{\sqrt{m+1}}{\sqrt{m+1}-\left(\sqrt{m+1}-\sqrt{m+3}\right)}=\dfrac{\sqrt{m+1}}{\sqrt{m+3}}$

$p(n)=\prod _{m=0}^n \dfrac{\sqrt{m+1}}{\sqrt{m+3}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt{(n+3)!}}=\color{blue}{\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{(n+2)(n+3)}}}$

*Thanks to **Steven Stadnicki** for the blue simplification!*

$
\begin{array}{l|l}
n & p(n)\\
\hline
 135 & 0.0102853 \\
 136 & 0.010211 \\
 137 & 0.0101378 \\
 138 & 0.0100656 \\
 \color{red}{139} & \color{red}{0.0099945} \\
 140 & 0.00992437 \\
\end{array}
$

Hope this can help

Comment: Note that your final expression can be simplified even more, to $\sqrt{\frac{2}{(n+2)(n+3)}}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you very much!

Comment: @Raffaele Thank you so much, yes this helps a lot! I'm a bit disappointed that I wasn't able to rewrite $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}$ as $(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})$. Is there a technique to this? like a 'rule'? or is it just meant to be obvious.

Comment: You multiply num and den by $\sqrt {k+1}-\sqrt{k}$ to get $$\dfrac{\sqrt {k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1})(\sqrt {k+1}-\sqrt{k})}$$ which gives $$\dfrac{\sqrt {k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{k+1-k}$$ like in $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I was just about to comment on that. Isn't $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{(n+1)(n+3)}}$ incorrect? I thought the correct simplification should be $\sqrt{\frac{2}{(n+2)(n+3)}}$

Comment: @Wyvnn Yes thank you: it was a typo of mine